# Is there any C library for drawing pictures and making .jpg files?

Tags: c, linux, yacc, lex, call-graph

I think this question might look very stupid and unnecessary but I really couldn't figure out how to solve this problem.

I need to make a call graph as a result of using some test codes written in C.

I made lex file and yacc file to parse the syntax.

Now I can make an executable file to parse a file written in C language with .l and .y files.

But now I have to make a jpg file and text file as a result of the executable file with the input file

The jpg file and text file need to show the calling relationship of functions in the input(Call graph)

So suppose there are files

```
lex.l yacc.y test.c
```

I need to make an executable file.

`lex lex.l`command make `lex.yy.c`

`yacc -d yacc.y` command make `y.tab.c` and `y.tab.h`(header for the lex file)

now `cc y.tab.c lex.yy.c` cammand will make an executable file `a.out`

so I have to make a jpg file(.jpg) and text file(.txt) as a result of `a.out < test.c` command

I know how to make a text file using fprintf() function.

But the jpg file is something that I really can't figure out.

I can't use some other tools

I only can just type some C codes to the lex file and the yacc file

So I think I might use some C library for doing this

Is there any way that I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: unless you have some code, this should be posted on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Why can't you use other tools? If that is homework, discuss with your teacher

Comment: If you are a beginner in programming, this looks quite an ambitious project. You'll need a few months of work.

Comment: @phuclv thank you but someone said there are other ways to do that without using tools. But it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to make a call graph as a result of using some test codes written in C.

You could [*fork*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) some *other* [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) doing the drawing and use [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facilities with it (and this is probably the simplest approach, since it conforms to the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)). Consider running some [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/) or maybe [GnuPlot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/) process. You need skills on Linux system programming (to use wisely several [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call),  which are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)), so you should read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) or something newer.

> so I have to make a jpg file(.jpg) and text file(.txt) as a result of `a.out < test.c` command

Don't name your program `a.out`, in 2019 it is ridiculous. Learn how to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). And learn to [use](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) the program arguments (you may want to use [parsing program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html) facilities). You'll invoke your program as `myprogram test.c` but be aware that *your shell* (the one you'll use to run your program) will do [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

And you could also make your program some [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) application (centered on some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) provided by the toolkit), using some [GUI toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) like [GTK](https://gtk.org/) or [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/). If you just want to *output* some graphics, you might consider also [libcairo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_(graphics)).

If you have [web programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development) skills, you could consider using web technologies (such as [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) + [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) + [Canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element)); if you want to make your program some specialized web server (e.g. your user would browse some http://localhost:12345 URL), consider using an [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) server library such as [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).

If you accept to produce some other kind of file having the drawing, consider emitting some SVG or PDF files. You'll find libraries for that too. BTW, SVG is a textual format that you could emit directly.

At last, you can find many libraries processing JPEG files, such as [libjpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg).

PS. You really should *find* on the Web some small *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://gitlab.org/), [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/), etc...) *similar* in spirit to your goals and *study its source code for inspiration*. By doing so, you'll learn a lot of practical things, and you'll save hours of work (because you apparently lack practical skills).

BTW, if your goal is to find the call graph of some real-life C program, consider making some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). I did that a few weeks ago (in about 800 lines of C++ code), for some uninteresting demo in relation with my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) research project. And if you do have to parse C code, you need to parse the preprocessed form of it. So run some `cpp` preprocessor to get that.

Comment: I’m really really thankful to your kindness. I will look closer to this answer in detail